# iOS 7 Remote notifications

Tags: ios, ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In a article I read that in iOS 7 something called Remote notifications was introduced. Is it similar to APN?

If my iPad run on a local area network, which doesn't have an internet connection, can I use this new Remote notifications option or is there any other new concept introduced in iOS 7 where I can send messages to the iPad without using internet(can't use APN).

Thanks.

Comment: Would be nice to include the link to the article you're referring to.

Comment: This is the article http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html

Answer (score 1):

Remote notifications is a synonym to Push Notifications, so it's not just similar to APN, it's the same thing. They require connection to the APN servers, and therefore they require internet connection.

> Local and push notifications serve different design needs. A local notification is local to an application on an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch. **Push notifications—also known as remote notifications**—arrive from outside a device. They originate on a remote server—the application’s provider—and are pushed to applications on devices (via the Apple Push Notification service) when there are messages to see or data to download.

([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1))

Comment: Thanks Eran for you reply. But in iOS 7 its not exactly the same. I posted the answer I found from Apple forum above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my first question from Apple forum.

"iOS 7 remote notifications are a small enhacement to the standard APN system. The only difference is that when they arrive, the application is given background time to react to the notification. With classic APN, the app isn't woken up until the user acts on the notification."

Comment: That doesn't change the answer to your main question. Since on the server side "remote notifications" equals APNS, you must have an internet connection.

Comment: Yes thats true. It's just the answer to my first question. Not to my problem. I'll update the answer. Do you know about any way that I can send a notification/message to a iPad without using internet? I'm stuck with this :-(